# Rails Routing and link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper, link-to

It's a little late here so maybe this a trivial question where I'm missing something simple. But when I click a button (with link_to) I created the following gets appended to my URL:

```
%23<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x3ef1fd8>
```

Why is this, and how can I prevent this? Again, I apologize if this is a shallow question. I can post more information regarding routes and whatnot if that is needed.

Thanks!

Edit: More information as requested.

View:

```
<%= link_to "Index", welcome_path(f), :class => 'button' %>
```

with f being part of a form_for loop. I think I'm passing the wrong parameter but I'm unsure.

Relevant Route:

```
get "index" => 'welcome#show', :as => 'index'
```

Update:

Thanks for the help everyone. I ended up getting it working by pluralizing my controller (I don't know why I didn't have that before) and utilizing welcome_url instead. That seemed to do the trick.

Comment: Can you also post the view code where you have this form and button?

Comment: We need more code to be able to see what is going on.

Comment: Hey guys, I added more information. Thanks again.

Comment: `welcome_path` does not need any parameter.

Comment: You might want to post all of the content of your `routes.rb` file.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the very first example and paragraph in the [Rails API docs for ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html):

```
<%= form_for @person do |f| %>
Name: <%= f.text_field :name %>
Admin: <%= f.check_box :admin %>
<% end %>
```

What this is saying is that `f` represents an instantiated FormBuilder object that you are passing to the `welcome_path` method in your `link_to` helper.

Typically, you would not mix #index and #show in your routes. Depending on what you want to use the `WelcomesController` for, you might actually want to route your `root_path` to `welcome_index`:

```
get "welcome/show" => 'welcome#show', :as => 'welcome'
root 'welcome#index'
```

You should run: `$ rake routes` in the terminal to get an idea of path view helpers that you can use in your app.

Maybe you're trying to send users to a personalized welcome page. You could have something like this for your corresponding `link_to` helpers would look best like this:

```
<%= link_to "Show", welcome_path(@user.id), :class => 'button %> 
<%= link_to "Index", root_path, :class => 'button' %>
```

Comment: This is a good explanation of how things operate. I'm still learning Rails routing and this is quite helpful. Thanks!